# Ways to participate

Tags: discussion, support, voting, community

It looks like the site has gotten off to good start, with a lot of interesting questions and answers! I just want to remind people of some of the other ways to participate that will help the site to grow. Some of these privileges might only be available to during the Private Beta if you haven't earned sufficient rep.

- [Voting](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/11): Upvoting/downvoting questions/answers gives a good indication that the site is being used, that people find it valuable, and what a good/bad post looks like on this site.
- Reviews/Editing: If you think you can improve the formatting/quality of a post or are worried a post in its current form doesn't fit the site well, try to edit it or vote to close so the user has time to make more substantial changes without getting heavily downvoted.
- Tags: Check that posts have tags that describe their content. A lot of other Meta sites on the network have guidance on what makes a useful tag, so see if you can add new tags that will describe a lot of posts or remove those that won't fit or don't relate to the content of a post. Also, when you create a new tag, add a description explaining the situations where it can be used.
- Ask about policy: If you aren't sure about taking some action on the site or just want to get a sense of the community's feelings on a particular issue, ask here on the Meta site.