# How are we doing in beta?

Tags: discussion, beta, area-51

Beta sites do not automatically make it to a full site. There are requirements we have to meet.

See: [What should the criteria be for Stack Exchange sites to leave beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331718/181143)

Where can one see how the users here are doing at fulfilling the requirements?

---

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242

---

I had to tag this with something so used discussion.

Think of this as more of a nice to know and bookmark in you browser before you forget.

---

End of week 1.

[image]

---

End of week 2.

[image]

---

End of week 3.

[image]

---

End of week 4.

[image]

---

Day: 30

Color coding of values appeared.

[image]

Notice that some of the wording changed.
From `currently N users with 200+ rep`
To `on pace for N users at 90 days`

---

Day: 34

This question was posted

[Leaving Private Beta & Initial Pro-Tem Moderator Election!](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/166/5)

and then this was given a close vote asking if that answered this question.

[image]

Well of course not. Moving from private beta to public beta is still beta.

[image]

Often after the election is over and long forgotten it is hard to find the election page, so here it is

Proof Assistants [2022 Moderator Election](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/election/1)

---

Note: When a site moves from private beta to public beta the amount rep needed for most privileges changes. While it takes more rep than private beta for many privileges it is still not as much rep as needed when out of beta.

Reputation for privileges in private beta.

[image]

Reputation for privileges in public beta.

[image]

---

Day: 34

Unexpected bonus when visiting https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242

Note: The rep is added to the the Area 51 account, not the Proof Assistants account. I wish it were the other way. :(

[image]

Also 56 beta badges have been awarded.

https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta

---

Day: 41

[2022 Community Moderator Election](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/2022-community-moderator-election) (Meta Announcement Page)
[2022 Moderator Election](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/election) (Election Page)
[Chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134978/2022-proof-assistants-stack-exchange-moderator-election-chat) specifically for the election.

The election chat room has an election bot. ([GitHub](https://github.com/samliew/se-electionbot)).

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Day 47

2022 Community Moderator Election starts in 1 hour.

[image]

When the clock is less than an hour it switches to minutes.

[image]

When the clock is less than a minute it switches to seconds. How thoughtful.

[image]

There were 6 candidates but one dropped out. Did not know that was possible. One user wanted to run but could not because they were suspended. ([ref](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60741999#60741999)). The candidates are listed randomly (click browser refresh and watch the list change).

For each candidate running there is an option to see their reviews and meta posts.

[image]

---

When the election begins you will receive a notification in your in box.

[image]

The ballot looks like

[image]

If you click `Learn more` on the ballot you will see

[image]

After you leave the page you will earn a badge for voting.

[image]

The vote tally does not update during the election so don't look for such while the election is running.

To know who voted check out the [Constituent badge](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/constituent) page.

Since it requires 150 reputation points to vote, at the start of the election only 126 users are eligible to vote.

The election page also has a count down clock.

[image]

The election has three phases (Nomination, Primary, Election) and the second phase (Primary) will be skipped if there are less than 30 candidates. However if one goes to the Primary tab of the election the vote buttons are present but voting is not allowed on that page.

[image]

Day 56

Election Results

https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/election

[image]

https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/constituent

[image]

For specifics of vote counts see

https://www.opavote.com/results/6675471908470784

---

Day 98

Today the first [Fanatic](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic) badges were awarded.

One would think this would happen on day 100 but it is day 98.

---

Day: 100

[image]

---

Day: 200

[image]

---

Day 364

First [Yearling badge](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) awarded 20x.

9 minutes latter 7 more were added. Odd that it tracks these down to the minute.

---

Day 366

[image]

Comment: Imagine if the site got scheduled for closure. :D Good job Proof Assistants Stack Exchange! :)

Comment: The +50 is on Area51.SE.

Comment: Questions per day has continued to fall, and is now at 1.4, eclipsing visits per day (which has been rising, maybe due to the election) as our stat with the highest ratio of desired to actual value.

Answer (score 12):

I followed the last three Private Beta sites religiously (Drones and Model Aircraft, Matter Modeling, and Cardano). ProofAssistants is doing very well.

I gave a very detailed comparison of some of those sites' first days in Private Beta, [here](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/a/39/149).

Overall, everything has been going as well as expected here at Proof Assistants, and this is with far less participation from CMs compared to the other sites I mentioned here.

**If we continue like this, I'm fairly certain we'll be approved to enter Public Beta!**

Keep up the ***voting*** on good content, and ***editing*** of poor content:
Previous sites have been required to have 100 *high-quality* questions in order to enter Public Beta, so let's keep up the good work and [Vote Early, Vote Often](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/8).