# Redirected to page announcing PA private beta?

Tags: bug, beta

I'm unable to navigate to the main Proof Assistants site. I was clicking on an item in my reputation changes notifications, and it brought up a page announcing the beta would become public "in a few days".  Various other things, such as trying to post a question on the main site, clicking my avatar, or choosing Proof Assistants from the drop list at upper right, produced basically the same result.

Perhaps this is an, expected behavior at the end of private beta?

**Update:** This seems to have been on a PC where I'd not yet "entered the private beta".  Once I'd clicked the button at the bottom of the page I could access Proof Assistants as on my other PC's. Oddly it allowed me to post to the meta site (this post) but not to see the main site.

Comment: I have not seen any problems. The only change I noted is noted [here](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-are-we-doing-in-beta) with the color coding.

Comment: I do not have any issues: perhaps this is an error on **your** end?

Comment: It is working now.  After I posted here I got the Site Down for Maintenance page when trying to navigate back from meta to main (using the drop down list at upper right).

Answer (score 3):

This is likely to be related to [this weekend's outages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377085/295232). Apparently, some parts of private beta sites react suboptimally to this, but I understand if they'd rather dedicate resources to prevent outages like these than to fix this particular behaviour.